# Что не так с активацией в моей нейронной сети? Почему оно не работает?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, numpy

Схема сети

[image: нейронная сеть]

У меня есть 2 набора точек, по 100 каждого.

[image: Отображение точек с делением на классы]

Я хочу обучить сеть, на этих наборах так, чтобы она могла понимать к какому классу будут относиться новые тестовые точки. С использованием лишь библиотеки *numpy*. Хочу понять как всё работает, а не использовать готовый функционал иных библиотек.

```
import numpy as np
data_1 = np.loadtxt('/points_1.txt')
data_2 = np.loadtxt('/points_2.txt')
data = np.vstack([data_1,data_2])
# нормализация в (0,1) :
data = (data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min())
x, y = data[:,0:1], data[:,1:2]
# эталонный вектор вероятностей принадлежности к классу :
y_standart = np.array([ [0]*100 + [1]*100, [1]*100 + [0]*100 ]).T
```

[image: Исходный набор точек]

```
# функция активации (сигмоида) :
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x * 1))
# производная функции активации (для BackPropagation)
def sigmoid_drvt(x):
         return 2*10*np.exp(-x * 10) / np.power(1+np.exp(-x * 10) ,2 )

nn_input_dim = 1 # размер входного слоя
nn_output_dim = 2 # размер выходного слоя
nn_hdim = 4 # количество узлов в скрытом слое
np.random.seed(0)
W1 = np.random.randn(nn_input_dim, nn_hdim) / np.sqrt(nn_input_dim)
b1 = np.zeros((1, nn_hdim))
W2 = np.random.randn(nn_hdim, nn_output_dim) / np.sqrt(nn_hdim)
b2 = np.zeros((1, nn_output_dim))
n = 10000 #количество эпох
for iter in range(n):

    # Прямое распространение:
    a1 = sigmoid( x.dot(W1) + b1 )
    a2 = sigmoid( a1.dot(W2) + b2 )

    # Обратное распространение:
    error_out = a2 - y_standart
    error_hidden = np.dot(error_out,W2.T)  
    #изменение весов:
    W2 += a1.T.dot( error_out * sigm_drv(a2) )
    b2 += ( error_out * sigm_drv(a2) ).sum(axis=0)
    W1 += x.T.dot( error_hidden * sigm_drv(a1) )
    b1 += ( error_hidden * sigm_drv(a1) ).sum(axis=0)
```

Всё вроде сделал по формулам, но на выходе единицы в обоих столбцах. Надо чтобы на выходе формировалась натренированная матрица вероятностей **a2** размерности *(количество точек, 2)* с двумя значениями вероятностей отвечающих за принадлежность к первому либо второму классу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы получить вероятность принадлежности к какому либо классу, нужно использовать кросс-энтропию как функцию ошибки и на выходном слое - softmax, как функцию активации. Вот простейшая реализация:

```
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

def softmax(z):
    return np.exp(z) / np.exp(z).sum()

def ReLU(z):
    return np.maximum(0, z)

def ReLU_deriv(s):
    return 1 * (s > 0)

def get_data(X, y):
    i = np.random.randint(0, X.shape[0])
    return X[i].reshape(-1,1), y[i].reshape(-1,1)

X = np.array([
    [1,1],
    [1,0],
    [0,1],
    [0,0],
])
y = np.array([[0,1],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1]])

w1 = np.random.random((2,2))
w2 = np.random.random((2,2))

bias1 = np.random.random((2,1))
bias2 = np.random.random((2,1))

etha = 0.1
epoch = 10000

losses = []

for _ in range(epoch):

    x_i, y_i = get_data(X, y)

    layer1_IN = x_i
    z1 = w1.T.dot(layer1_IN) + bias1
    layer1_OUT = ReLU(z1)

    layer2_IN = layer1_OUT
    z2 = w2.T.dot(layer2_IN) + bias2
    layer2_OUT = softmax(z2)

    #loss = -(y_i * np.log(layer_OUT)).sum()
    #losses.append(loss)

    delta2 = layer2_OUT - y_i
    delta1 = delta2.T.dot(w2.T) * ReLU_deriv(layer1_OUT).T

    grad2 = delta2.dot(layer2_IN.T)
    grad1 = delta1 * layer1_IN

    w2 -= etha * grad2.T
    bias2 -= etha * delta2

    w1 -= etha * grad1
    bias1 -= etha * delta1.reshape(-1,1)

for x in X:
    x = x.reshape(-1,1)
    print(softmax(w2.T.dot(ReLU(w1.T.dot(x) + bias1)) + bias2).T)
```

Если нужны объяснения по какой-либо части кода - спрашивайте, объясню. Старался писать так чтобы интуитивно было все понятно. В случае двух классовой классификации вернее будет использовать бинарную кросс энтропию в качестве функции ошибки и sigmoid в качестве функции активации.

Comment: Почему не используется производная функции активации выходного слоя (softmax) ?

Comment: `layer2_OUT - y_i` вот это производня категориальной кросс энтропии с функцией активации softmax, все используется, такая вот короткая производная выходит после всех вычислений.